# Replication_factor is an option for SimpleStrategy, not NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I Don't know why  this happening

```
ConfigurationException: <ErrorMessage code=2300 [Query invalid because of configuration issue] message="replication_factor is an option for SimpleStrategy, not NetworkTopologyStrategy">
```

My Query:

```
Create keyspace university with replication={'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','replication_factor':'3'};
```

Can Anyone tell what is wrong with my query!?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkTopologyStrategy allows you to define different replication for each DC.

So, from a CQL perspective a correct query would be

```
CREATE KEYSPACE NTSkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };
```

I suggest reading [this article](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html) about how to create a keyspace. There you will find the right parameters for NetworkTopologyStrategy.